# Why is getResources().getColor(int) deprecated?

Tags: android, android-theme

The document says:

> This method was deprecated in API level 23. Use `getColor(int, Theme)`
>   instead.

And many posts point to the `ContextCompat.getColor(Context, int)` method as a replacement.

Also the document explains the `Theme` parameter:

> theme Resources.Theme: The theme used to style the color attributes,
>   may be null.

Can you explain how can the theme affects the color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some complex colors like `android.content.res.GradientColor` (which are used inside a `VectorDrawable`) need a Theme in order to inflate the gradient, since you could have a definition like:

```
<gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <android:startColor="?android:attr/colorPrimary"/>
   <android:endColor="?android:attr/colorControlActivated"/>
   <android:type="linear"/>
 </gradient>
```

Comment: Ah I see. The Resources class also has a getColorStateList(int, Theme) method and a deprecated version for that method too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as a workaround:
ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourcolor)